# How to add condition to Array to concatenate Columns A&B only if Column B value is not blank?

Tags: concatenation, google-sheets-formula, flatten, google-query-language, textjoin

Trying to display output of columns A & B when value in column B is present in a single cell.

I can join all of the non blank value in column B by using textjoin, combining a filter & an array I can get the output in two steps.

But I am wondering if there is a way to do this in one step such as combining the array & filter function or in some other way?

[image]

[here is a link to spreadsheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1exBWFLTgPRFipaimJYTQ5Mi0J5EsawEVkwd11IyJ8Gc/edit?usp=sharing)

---

I think maybe this can be accomplished by substituting any of the "subjects" that are not followed by an answer. Possibly using a Regex replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A:B, B:B<>"")),,9^9)))
```

[image]

or:

```
=TRIM(JOIN(, FILTER(A:A&" "&B:B&CHAR(10), B:B<>"")))
```

[image]

---

### update

```
=INDEX(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(A2:E6="",,"♦"&A1:E1&" "&A2:E6)),,9^9)), "♦", CHAR(10))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can I modify this if the data were displayed in column ranges?

Comment: Thanks. Can I modify this if the data were displayed in column ranges? So that instead of combining values in A1& B2 in a range of A1:B5, the header values in the range of say A1:Z1 are combined with the values in each row below them if they are not blank? See tab 2 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1exBWFLTgPRFipaimJYTQ5Mi0J5EsawEVkwd11IyJ8Gc/edit#gid=790266422

Comment: I'm going to ask this as a separate question I think.

Comment: @MMsmithH answer updated